# How to resolve the issue with responsive lines in css when the browser is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have tried drawing 4 vertical equidistant lines as shown in the image. The lines come out of the container when the browser is resized. How can I make it stay within the container irrespective of the browser size? I am new to CSS.
Please let me know if more details are needed on this.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.bar {
  flex-grow: .8;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.blackline {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.line1 {
  left: 0%;
}

.line2 {
  left: 30%;
}

.line3 {
  left: 60%;
}

.line4 {
  left: 89%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line line1"></div>
  <div class="line line2"></div>
  <div class="line line3"></div>
  <div class="line line4"></div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="blackline"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The expected result is to have the 1st line drawn at the container's start point, the last line at the end of the container and the two lines in between be equidistant from each other.

The desired result
[image: The desired result]

Comment: Please go through media query as per screen size

Comment: What's the expected result? Can you be more clear or include some image for reference

Comment: show the result image so we know what you exactly want.

Comment: Is the `enter image description here` is your desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add parent div for lines and use `Flex` property for that. So, you get equal distance in all the responsive windows. Below is the sample code for your image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


.container{
      width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
 .inner-container {
      display: flex;
    flex:1;
    position: relative;
}

.bar {
    flex-grow: .8;
    display: flex;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}



.blackline {
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
}
.line-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 100%;
}
.line {
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
                     
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="line-container">    
        <div class="line line1"></div>
        <div class="line line2"></div>
        <div class="line line3"></div>
        <div class="line line4"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="blackline"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my attempt which utilizing the advantage of flex without `position`. The usage of `position:absolute` is actually breaking the flex position. So I restructure your container and css to have as minimal as it can for the syntax to achieve your desired result.

The magic for the equal sizing of each `.line` is the following:

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

Here a very good reference for understanding flex better: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Not sure is it what you want but hope it helps~

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  flex-grow: .8;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.blackline {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

.line {
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.line:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="blackline"></div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="line line1"></div>
  <div class="line line2"></div>
  <div class="line line3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use margin on your container instead of padding and use space between on your inner container flex (instead of absolute positioning), then you can absolutely position your lines 1/3rd apart and use right 0 for your last line

```css
.container {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bar {
  flex-grow: 0.8;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.blackline {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.line1 {
  left: 0;
}

.line2 {
  left: 33.3333%;
}

.line3 {
  left: 66.6667%;
}

.line4 {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line line1"></div>
  <div class="line line2"></div>
  <div class="line line3"></div>
  <div class="line line4"></div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="blackline"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice  and expert